# Generating a rolling tally based on criterion

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

## Problem description

I am working with a spreadsheet of conflict events in the United States. Each row represents a single event and has geographic and temporal information included. Conflict events tend to occur in 'waves' (relatively tight temporal groupings). I have generated an identity variable for each of these waves and would like to create a variable that measures the geographic spread of these conflict events within each wave.

I am using Excel to do this. The data are already sorted by region, date, and wave.

## Data description

The dataset is structured as follows:

```
Country     Region     Date       Event     Wave
-------     -------    ------     -------   ------
USA         Vermont    5/1/2017   Strike    Wave 1
USA         Vermont    5/2/2017   Strike    Wave 1
USA         New Hamp.  5/3/2017   Strike    Wave 1
USA         Vermont    5/3/2017   Strike    Wave 1
USA         Maine      5/4/2017   Strike    Wave 1
USA         Washingt.  8/16/2018  Riot      Wave 2
USA         Washingt.  8/18/2018  Riot      Wave 2
USA         Oregon     8/18/2018  Protest   Wave 2
USA         Californ.  8/19/2018  Riot      Wave 2
USA         Nevada     8/20/2018  Protest   Wave 2
USA         Idaho      8/20/2018  Riot      Wave 2
```

## What I want to create

I want to create a variable ("geo_disp") that records the number of **regions** that have experienced conflict within a given **wave**. You will notice that when two events occur on the same day but in different locations, BOTH are recorded with the total number of regions. Here is what I want the data to look like:

```
Country     Region     Date       Event     Wave    geo_disp
-------     -------    ------     -------   ------  --------
USA         Vermont    5/1/2017   Strike    Wave 1   1
USA         Vermont    5/2/2017   Strike    Wave 1   1
USA         New Hamp.  5/3/2017   Strike    Wave 1   2
USA         Vermont    5/3/2017   Strike    Wave 1   2
USA         Maine      5/4/2017   Strike    Wave 1   3
USA         Washingt.  8/16/2018  Riot      Wave 2   1
USA         Washingt.  8/18/2018  Riot      Wave 2   2
USA         Oregon     8/18/2018  Protest   Wave 2   2
USA         Californ.  8/19/2018  Riot      Wave 2   3
USA         Nevada     8/20/2018  Protest   Wave 2   5
USA         Idaho      8/20/2018  Riot      Wave 2   5
```

How can I create the **geo_disp** variable using Excel?

Thank you in advance - I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Why in the first Wave does Vermont up 3 times in wave 1  adding only 1 to the geo_disp count, while Washingt. twice in Wave 2 and it adds 2.?

Comment: @BradR this is a distinct count of locations within the wave, on or before the date on the current row. The complexity is this point about "both locations on the same date contribute to the geo_disp for that date". Otherwise, we would expect the Nevada row in Wave 2 to say geo_disp=4.

Comment: Dear @Owen - I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

Comment: Dear @BradR - this is because in Wave 2, there are concurrent events in Washington and Oregon on the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel 365 and have access to the dynamic array functions FILTER and UNIQUE, you can do this:

[image]

geo_disp_1:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$4:$B4,$E$4:$E4=$E4)))
```

geo_disp:

```
=MAXIFS($F$4:$F$14,$E$4:$E$14,$E4,$C$4:$C$14,$C4)
```

**This is the process I took to get there**

First, I knew that I could use TRANSPOSE to return an array of vertical items horizontally. That enabled me, with use of a range that is anchored to the first row, to produce this:

[image]

I realised I wanted to restart those lists when the Wave changed, so I used FILTER to only pass into the TRANSPOSE function the rows whose wave matched the current wave.

[image]

This is slightly better, but I don't want duplicates. So, I can use UNIQUE to remove them, and remember that I need to set the second parameter to TRUE because this is a horizontal array.

[image]

Now it's just a matter of counting the items in each row:

[image]

After working through it visually like that, I converted it to something simpler. You don't actually need to transpose the array in this way. That's how I landed on the formula for geo_disp_1 (shown above).

The last remaining challenge was to make sure that this "multiple regions on the same date" issue was accounted for. I didn't immediately see an obvious way to do this without a separate column which took the MAX of geo_disp_1 based on the wave and date being the same.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I don't seem to have access to either UNIQUE or FILTER; however, I may be able to get Office 365 via my university.